# "inconsistent" match result when using code block in regex [Raku]

Tags: regex, match, raku, modifier

While checking and testing various aspects of regexes, I stumbled upon a strange and "incosistent" behaviour. I was trying to use some code in a regex, but the same behaviour applies also with use of a void code block.
Especially what moved me the most, was the difference in the match result when I interchanged the :g vs the :x modifiers.

The following code snippets depict the "inconsistent" behaviour.

First without the code block:

```
use v6.d;

if "test1 test2 test3 test4" ~~ m:g/ (\w+) / {
    say ~$_ for $/.list;
}
```

Result:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

then with the :g modifier and the code block:

```
use v6.d;

if "test1 test2 test3 test4" ~~ m:g/ (\w+) {} / {
    say ~$_ for $/.list;
}
```

Result:

```
test4
```

and finally with the :x modifier and the code block

```
use v6.d;

if "test1 test2 test3 test4" ~~ m:x(4)/ (\w+) {} / {
    say ~$_ for $/.list;
}
```

Result:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

I expected the three results to be the same but I was negatively surprised.

Is there any explanation about this behaviour?

Comment: The problem has been fixed by Jonathan Worthington: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/1e0474d4fc0d0ab2e0e36121149d706e27af73ae

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** [Issue filed by @jakar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3554) and [fixed by jnthn](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/1e0474d4fc0d0ab2e0e36121149d706e27af73ae).

---

(Rewritten after more testing and code spelunking.)

This looks to me (and presumably you) like a bug. `$/` is somehow getting kiboshed when using `:g` and an embedded block.

This answer covers:

- **Zeroing in on the problem**
- **Looking at the compiler's source code**
- **Searching issue queues and/or filing a new issue**

## Zeroing in on the problem

```
my &debug = {;} # start off doing no debugging
$_ = 'aa';

say       m      / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # ｢a｣
say $/ if m      / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # ｢a｣

say       m:x(2) / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
say $/ if m:x(2) / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # (｢a｣ ｢a｣)

say       m:g    / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
say $/ if m:g    / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # ｢a｣ <--- Uhoh
```

Now make `debug` say something useful and run the first pair (without a regex adverb):

```
&debug = { say $_, $/.WHICH } # Say location of object bound to `$/`

say       m      / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # ｢a｣
# 1Match|66118928
# 2Match|66118928
# ｢a｣
# 3Match|66118928

say $/ if m      / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # ｢a｣
# 1Match|66119072
# 2Match|66119072
# ｢a｣
# 3Match|66119072
```

The same simple result in both cases. The match process creates a `Match` object and sticks with the same one.

Now the two variations with the `:x(2)` adverb:

```
say       m:x(2) / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
# 1Match|66119936
# 2Match|66119936
# 1Match|66120080
# 2Match|66120080
# 1Match|66120224
# (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
# 3List|67612624

say $/ if m:x(2) / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
# 1Match|66120368
# 2Match|66120368
# 1Match|66120512
# 2Match|66120512
# 1Match|66120656
# (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
# 3List|67612672
```

This time the match process creates a `Match` object and sticks with it for one pass, then a second match object for a second pass, and finally  a third match object for a third pass before it fails to match a third `'a'` (and hence the corresponding `debug 2` doesn't get called). At the end of the `m.../.../` call it has created a `List` object and bound *that* to `$/`.

Next we run the first of the two `:g` cases:

```
say       m:g    / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
# 1Match|66119216
# 2Match|66119216
# 1Match|66119360
# 2Match|66119360
# 1Match|66119504
# (｢a｣ ｢a｣)
# 3Match|66119504
```

Like the `x:(2)` case, we try a third time and fail. But the match process does *not* return a `List` but instead a `Match` object. And it's the one created in the third pass. (Which surprises me.)

Finally, there's the "Uhoh" case:

```
say $/ if m:g    / {debug 1} 'a' {debug 2} /; debug 3; # ｢a｣ <--- Uhoh
# 1Match|66119648
# 2Match|66119648
# 1Match|66119792
# 2Match|66119792
# ｢a｣
# 3Match|66119792
```

Remarkably, the expected third pass appears not to start.

## Looking at the compiler's source code

It's plausible that exploring the relevant source code would be valuable. I'll write about that here in case it's of interest to you or other readers and in case this is a bug and what I write is of interest to someone fixing it.

Afaict a code block in a regex leads to an AST node being generated [here](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/9e1125435a079c8a1b937eaeffc017285dff168e/src/QRegex/P6Regex/Actions.nqp#L197-L209) that inserts a sub-node ahead of the statements in the block that does a bind operation:

```
                    :op('bind'),

                    QAST::Var.new( :name('$/'), :scope('lexical') ),

                    QAST::Op.new(
                        QAST::Var.new( :name('$¢'), :scope('lexical') ),
                        :name('MATCH'),
                        :op('callmethod')
                    )
```

My read of the above is that it inserts code that binds the lexical `$/` symbol to the result of a `.MATCH` method call on the object bound to the lexical `$¢` symbol immediately prior to running the code in the block.

The doc has [a section on `$¢`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Match#index-entry-$%C2%A2); I'll quote a sentence:

> The main difference between `$/` and `$¢` is scope: the latter only has a value inside [a] regex

I'm left wondering why `$¢` exists and what other differences there are.

Moving on...

I see there's [a raku level `.MATCH`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/21aa02ba0dbbc55a30c278660c111bf928e0119f/src/core.c/Match.pm6#L22). But it barely does anything. So I presume the code that's relevant is [here](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/9a12c17c161412ee1f146900b37366b33f89424e/src/QRegex/Cursor.nqp#L1087-L1188).

At this point I'll pause. I might continue further in a later edit.

## Searching issue queues and/or filing a new issue

If someone comes up with an answer in the next few days demonstrating that what you've shown isn't a bug, or has already been filed as a bug, then fair enough.

Otherwise, please consider doing your own search of the issue queues and/or starting a new issue in whatever issue queue you consider the most appropriate (default to /rakudo/rakudo/issues).

I've already searched the four github.com issue queues I considered plausibly relevant as part of writing this answer:

- https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues
- https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues
- https://github.com/perl6/nqp/issues
- https://github.com/moarvm/moarvm/issues

I searched for two keywords that I hoped might uncover an existing issue ("global" and "publish"). No matching issues were relevant. Perhaps you can also look for other keywords that you think a filer might use.

If you do file an issue, please consider adding your tests, or mine or  some other variant, converted into standard roast test cases, if you know how to do that.

Comment: Thnx for your time and effort. I'll wait for a few days for response and if not fruitful I'll proceed as directed by you! I won't promote your answer as "accepted" until the matter is final.

Comment: Filled a bug report on github (rakudo): https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3554